# If a line and its points are removed from a projective geometry, is the resulting is affine geometry?

Tags: projective-geometry, affine-geometry

I saw that it's written in a couple of places, but couldn't find proper proof for this.

I saw it for example in:

[here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2510042/if-a-line-and-its-points-are-removed-from-a-projective-plane-is-the-resulting-s) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_geometry)

I would like to find a reference to a proof of this (as I'm sure some book or a thing like that addresses the problem) or the proof itself.

I hope it's legit to ask for this.

Comment: You are looking at a projective plane, not a general projective space - if you identify the line you remove with a "line at infinity" you should find things work out. The real case for general dimension I think is covered in Coxeter's "Introduction to Geometry"

Comment: Is pg 21 of [this chapter](http://www.maths.qmul.ac.uk/~pjc/pps/pps2.pdf) the sort of thing that you're looking for?  If not, where does it fall short?

Answer (score 1):

Let $E$ be a vector space over the field $\Bbb K$, and let

$$ \mathcal P(E) = \big\{F\subseteq E\;\; : \;\; F \text{ subspace of  } E, \;\dim(F)=1\big\} \;=\;
\big\{\text{vector (straight) lines of } E\big\} $$

be the projective space induced by $E$.

If $H$ is a hyperplane of $E$, i.e. $\mathcal P(H)\:$ is, by definition, a hyperplane of $\mathcal P(E)$, we want to prove that

$$ \mathcal A := \mathcal P(E)\setminus\mathcal P(H) \tag{1}$$

is an affine space contained in $\mathcal P(E)$, with associated translation space $H$, also denoted $\;\mathcal A(H)$.

Since $H$ is a hyperplane of $E$, we have $\;\text{codim}(H)=1$, hence there exists $\;a\in E, \;a\neq0,$ such that

$$ E=H\oplus \langle a\rangle. \tag{2}$$

For each $v\in E$, we have $\;v=h+\lambda a\;$ for suitable and uniquely determined $\;h\in H\;$ and $\;\lambda\in\Bbb K$; as the vectors $\;h\in H\;$ are obtained for $\;\lambda= 0$, we can write

$$ \mathcal P(E) = \mathcal P(H)\,\dot\cup\,\big\{\big\langle h+\lambda a\big\rangle\;\; :\;\;h\in H, \;\lambda\in\Bbb R, \;\lambda\neq 0\big\}, \tag{3}$$

where $\;\dot\cup\;$ denote the disjoint union.

Now, we observe that the set $\,\mathcal A\,$ after the disjoint union sign in $(3)$ is equal to

$$ \mathcal A = \big\{\big\langle h+a\big\rangle\;\;:\;\;h\in H\big\}. $$

Indeed, being $\;\lambda\neq 0,\;$ we have

$$ \big\langle h+\lambda a\big\rangle = \big\langle \lambda\lambda^{-1}h+\lambda a\big\rangle = \big\langle \lambda\big(\lambda^{-1}h+a\big)\big\rangle = \big\langle\lambda^{-1}h+a\big\rangle, $$

and obviously $\;\lambda^{-1}h\;$ describes $\;H\;$ as $\;h\;$ describes $\;H$.

The points of $\;\mathcal A(H)\;$ are therefore by definition the projective points lying in $\; \mathcal P(E)\setminus \mathcal P(H)\;$, i.e. $(1)$ holds.

Finally, $\;\mathcal A(H)\;$ is an affine space through the structure defined by the function

$$ \phi\; : \; \mathcal A(H) \times \mathcal A(H) \;\;\longrightarrow\;\; H $$

defined by

$$ \phi\big(\big\langle h_1+a\big\rangle, \big\langle h_2+a\big\rangle\big) := h_2-h_1, $$

as it is easy to verify.

As a last observation, it can also be easily verified that the preceding construction of $\;\mathcal A(H)\;$ does not depend on the choice of $\;a\;$ in $(2)$. In fact, if $\,a'\neq0\,$ is another vector satisfying $(2)$, and denoted $\,\mathcal A'(H)\,$ the affine space so obtained, the function

$$ f\;:\; \langle h+a\rangle \longmapsto \langle h+a'\rangle\; $$

from $\;\mathcal A(H)\;$ to $\;\mathcal A'(H)\;$ is an affine isomorphism.